Warning: "Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus" in Angular modal
I'm encountering a warning in my Angular application that states:

Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus. The focus must not be hidden from assistive technology users. Avoid using aria-hidden on a focused element or its ancestor. Consider using the inert attribute instead.

I'm using a modal dialog created with the Angular Bootstrap (ng-bootstrap) library. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Serial Number</h4>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" aria-label="Close" (click)="popupClose(false)">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

Issue:
The warning indicates that an element with aria-hidden is blocking focus from its descendant elements. I want to ensure that my modal is accessible and does not cause issues for assistive technology users.
I considered using the inert attribute as suggested, but I’m unsure how to implement it in this context.
I've looked through the ng-bootstrap documentation and found no specific guidance on this warning.

Let's suppose this is how you're using the NgbModal to open the modal inside your angular component:
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';
import { MODAL_CONFIG } from './modal-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<button type="button" (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  openModal() {
    this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, MODAL_CONFIG.MEDIUM); // Open the modal
  }
}

Now you will see expected warning which occurs because of how ng-bootstrap manages modals. When a modal is opened, ng-bootstrap adds aria-hidden="true" to the 'app-root' element to make it inaccessible to assistive technologies while the modal is active.
However, at this moment:

The element that triggered the modal (e.g., the "Open Modal" button)
retains focus.
Since the button is inside app-root, and app-root now has
aria-hidden="true", this creates an accessibility conflict. Assistive
technologies flag this as an issue because the focused element is
effectively hidden.

To resolve this, remove the focus from the button (or any triggering element) before opening the modal. This prevents the focused element from being inside the aria-hidden="true" ancestor.
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';
import { MODAL_CONFIG } from './modal-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: '<button type="button" (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  openModal() {
    const buttonElement = document.activeElement as HTMLElement; // Get the currently focused element
    buttonElement.blur(); // Remove focus from the button
    this.modalService.open(ModalComponent, MODAL_CONFIG.MEDIUM); // Open the modal
  }
}


EDIT 1

It would be hard to incorporate this solution to a large project. Therefore it would be better to use a custom service which will remove focus from the active element every time NgbModal.open is called.
Here's how you can do this:
Create a service in your project like this:
export class CustomModalService extends NgbModal {
  override open(content: unknown, options?: NgbModalOptions): NgbModalRef {
    const activeElement = document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
    if (activeElement) {
      activeElement.blur();
    }

    return super.open(content, options);
  }
}

Now just add this class in your providers array in the app.module.ts:
providers: [
    { provide: NgbModal, useClass: CustomModalService }
  ]

Now whenever you open up a modal it will call our custom modal service first which will take care of the aria-hidden error.

Even if the service makes sense, you may not want to remove the focus on each element. Maybe using a directive could make sense, so that you adds it to each button where you wish their focus to be removed.

@RaphaëlBalet I agree introducing a directive is more practical and better approach but only for projects which are in the development stage or for new components. For a large, already-developed project, adding a directive to every triggering element would require extensive code changes, which is more of a headache at this point.

This warning occurs when an element or one of its ancestors has the aria-hidden="true" attribute, which hides the element from assistive technologies like screen readers. However, if this element (or any of its descendants) is focusable, assistive technology users may still "see" it, which can create a confusing user experience.
Here's how you can resolve it:

Remove aria-hidden="true" from any element that has focusable children (like buttons). Focusable elements should not be hidden from assistive technology users, so it’s best to avoid using aria-hidden="true" on these elements or their ancestors.

Use the inert attribute if you need to make the element temporarily inactive or "invisible" for both interaction and focus purposes. The inert attribute prevents both keyboard focus and interaction, which can be useful if you’re working with modals or dynamically displayed content. However, note that inert is not supported in all browsers, so you may need a polyfill.

Check the modal logic: If you are using Bootstrap modals, ensure that the aria-hidden="true" attribute is not added to elements that will have focus. Sometimes, these attributes can be added by JavaScript frameworks or libraries, so check your modal configuration.


Here’s an example of how to adjust your button:
<button type="button" class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>

By removing aria-hidden="true" and using aria-label to improve accessibility, you avoid the conflict with focusable elements. If you need the button hidden temporarily, consider setting it to display: none instead, as it will remove it from the accessibility tree entirely.

Horizontal scroll are the bane of UX experience and presenting your answer this way does not help its readability.

If you are working with Bootstrap modal dialogs and encountering issues with focus management due to modern browser updates, the following code can help. It ensures that focus is removed from the active element whenever a modal is closed. This is particularly useful for any use case involving modals, whether they are nested, dynamically generated, or standard modal windows:
document.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // Снимаем фокус с активного элемента
    if (document.activeElement) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    }
});


To fix "Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus..." error on chrome.
I use this code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
        if (document.activeElement) {
            document.activeElement.blur();
        }
    });
});


doesn't work with Angular 18



//fix using a custom class

//example

export class DialogService {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  public open(component: ComponentType<unknown>, config?: MatDialogConfig) {
    this.removeActiveFocus();
    return this.dialog.open(component, config);
  }

  /**
   * Remove active focus from the document
   */
  private removeActiveFocus() {
    if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
      document.activeElement.blur();
    }
  }
  
}

//app.module.ts

providers: [
    {
      provide: DialogService,
      useFactory: (dialog: MatDialog) => new DialogService(dialog),
      deps: [MatDialog],
    },
]




This is the only solution that seems to work for me with A18 and latest Chrome. The srcElement blur on the button that was clicked kept throwing the aria-hidden warning. But this one seems to suppress it

As @Abhinav Kumar nicely explained, the issue is the original button retaining focus, once modal opens.
I ended up going with custom directive which I will provide here:
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[appBlurOnClick]'
})
export class BlurOnClickDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.blur();
  }
}

and then just use the directive on button opening modal:
<button mat-button appBlurOnClick (click)="openSignupDialog()">Sign Up</button>


Workaround fix to this would be to ... just remove the aria-hidden="true" from your span - that way the error will not appear.
